# binary search tree iterative insert simplest version

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write the simplest version (uses less code lines) to write an iterative insert for binary search trees.

This what I did:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
} Node;

Node* insert_BST_it(Node* root, int v) {
  Node* r = root, *hold, *node = create_node_bst(v);;
  int left = 0;
  while (r) {
    left = 0;
    if (elm <= r->data) {
      hold = r;
      r = r->left;
      left = 1;
    }
    else {
      hold = r;
      r = r->right;
      left = 0;
    }
  }
  if (left)
    hold->left = node;
  else
    hold->right = node;
  return root;
}
```

How would you do a simpler one?

Comment: Have you tried with recursion instead of a while loop?

Comment: Yes, that one is easier.

Comment: No need for both `int left = 0, right = 0;`. `bool left;` is sufficient.

Comment: @Kim, Code fails to compile.  Fix that first and worry about _simplest version_ after: 1) correctly compiling 2) correct functionality 3) proper error handling.

Comment: How does your code eve work? `if (left)`is outside the scope of the variable (which is inside the loop)  [same for `right`]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would you do a simpler (iterative) one?

- Instead of walking the BST with a `Node *`, use a `Node **` so we can easily update `root` if needed.  IOWs, as code walks the tree, keep track of the *address* of the pointer that needs updating.

Untested simpler code:

```
Node *insert_BST_it(Node *root, int val) {
  Node **current = &root;
  while (*current) {
    current = (*current)->data <= val ? &(*current)->left : &(*current)->right;
  }
  *current = create_node_bst(val);
  return root;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Node *root = 0;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  root = insert_BST_it(root, rand());
  assert(root);  // Test for insertion failure somehow.
}
```